# DataTables change pagination prev/next button of laravel backpack

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I use https://backpackforlaravel.com/
by default, it shows :
[image] 
but i want applying it : <kbd>Previous</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd> <kbd>5</kbd> <kbd>...</kbd> <kbd>10</kbd> <kbd>Next</kbd> on all pages .
i don't see `<` or `>`. Thank you in advance

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: @DilipHirapara i use backpack -for-laravel it's a Laravel Admin Panels. Simplified. https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD

Comment: I found the solution, I had to move the file list.blade.php located in <br>`vendor/backpack/crud/src/resources/views/crud/list.blade.php` to <br> `resources/views/vendor/backpack` and edit file .